# Is Lords of Waterdeep applicable to determining what is possible in the world of 5e (or 4e) on Rpg.se?

Tags: discussion, dnd-5e, citations

Noting that *Lords of Waterdeep* (LOW) comes with a "Rulebook" that is labeled not merely "Lords of Waterdeep / Rulebook" but rather says "Lords of Waterdeep / ***Dungeons & Dragons*** / Rulebook" (emphasis mine), I wonder if therefore the contents of LOW could and should be employed to answer questions about 5e (or 4e) that arise sometimes on this stack, at least questions of the format, "Is X possible in 5e, and if so, by what means?"

As an example, I will use a hypothetical question about owl bears. It would be normal on this stack to ask (and answer) a question such as "Can adventurers domesticate owlbears?".  If we were to deem Lords of Waterdeep irrelevant, we would answer by the usual WotC souces (core rulebooks and published modules, etc).

But what if we were to consider *Lords of Waterdeep* a "governing" source for this question?

Well, then we would notice that there is a Quest Card in LOW titled "Domesticate Owlbears", from which we can derive the following knowledge:

- Yes, it is possible for adventurers to domesticate owlbears.
- Specifically it requires one cleric and two wizards to do so, though
  it does not require any other adventurers beyond these.
- The result will be that the owlbears are suitable to being used, for example,
  by the City Guard of Waterdeep.
- After the duration of the process, at least two owlbears would have been domesticated (given that it is plural, not singular).
- Finally, since this task can be completed in roughly the same time as other random quests (which are all roughly speaking side quests, not module-size endeavors), it therefore must
  not take a tremendously longer time than the average side quest takes
  to complete.  Conversely, that it is a "quest-length" task in the
  first place means it doesn't take just five minutes (it is not a lot
  quicker than the typical side quest).

That's quite a lot of things to be settled, but of course it would not settle what level the cleric and wizards needed to be, nor how many owlbears (if any beyond two) could be domesticated together, nor the precise length of time (other than being in the typical range of time that side quests take).  But it would help us quite a lot in answering the question.

That is just one example, for purpose of illustration, and I am not particularly interested in owlbears here, just in the validity (or lack thereof) of this approach generally.

Some additional things I believe are relevant, but not immediately obvious how to interpret, are the facts around timing. *Lords of Waterdeep* was released in 2012, the year that WotC was developing 5e.  *Lords of Waterdeep* was issued an expansion in 2013, when WotC released the playtest packet for 5e. Does this mean Lords of Water deep is slightly "too early" to be considered, and that it should be relegated, if it applies to any table-top adjudications, to 4e only?  Or is still "part of canon" in a way that can make it binding for 5e?

Given all the above, can we settle whether it is OK to cite LoW in answering D&D 5e/4e questions on this site?

Comment: Is it possible to migrate this to main? This isn’t an appropriate question for meta.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov You should be able to vote to close this to have it migrated to main (under "Community Specific" now I think). Though I disagree with you personally. This question is asking whether we should consider it part of canon/RAW, that's a meta question/frame. A mainsite Q along the lines of "Is LoW part of 4e/5e?" might work, but probably wouldn't be very good.

Comment: Am I missing something here? This question asks if rules from one game apply in any way to another game. That is in no way a question about rpg.se, but exactly the kind of question we answer on main every single day. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of meta? This one seems *particularly* obvious that it’s a main question not a meta question. @Someone_Evil I’m sorry if my tone sounds offputting here, I’m just really confused.

Comment: @Someone_Evil To add some more thoughts, V2Blast’s answer below has absolutely nothing to do with the function of the site at all. All it does is explain the relationship between some rule sets. I don’t learn anything about rpg.se or our community by reading this Q&A, which I’ve come to expect when reading meta.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Hmm... I suppose that's a fair point. The core of the question is better suited to main, but the frame of the question is very much suited for meta and it's awkward to migrate a question as a frame challenge. My specific concern is perhaps that it can't really go on main without a major overhaul to its frame and still would probably not be a great question there either.

Comment: This might be a case of the title question being quite different to the body question. The title is quite directly a question about site practices; the body is an investigation into canonicity and authorial adjudications which honestly are kind of secondary. At least part of this belongs on meta, because it's asking how we do things here on this site. I'd tentatively put some blame for that mess on the Stack Q&A system literally instructing people on the ask page to state their question in the title and use the body merely to expand on it.

Comment: For what it's worth, this question was [originally asked on the main site (10k rep required to see the deleted post)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/175354/14878) but I left a comment asking for clarity and stated that if the question was about site practices then it should be asked on meta. The post was then moved here, to meta, without any further discussion.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey It would be very insightful if you submitted an answer with your perspective as to why you thought it belonged here vs on main site. Or maybe just a comment with that perspective.

Comment: FWIW yes, the way the initial comment from @PurpleMonkey was couched, did convince me to move it to meta.  At the time I believed it was about what *this* site defined as relevant, eligible material for deciding things in a 5e (or 4e) game. The first comment above from Someone_Evil is spot on... I wanted to know if we should consider it part of canon, and that seemed meta-ish. Happy to stand corrected and migrate it back to main if that is the consensus.

Comment: Isn't *every* question asked on main a question about what this site thinks about something or other? Who else would it be asking?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Uhh... it's slightly odder than that. A mainsite question shouldn't really be asking the communities opinion on something, it should be asking experts about what is correct/the best way to do something (or eqv.). If it is asking the community for how it should do something, it's better of on meta. This is odd because there's a version of this question for either and the mainsite question is probably cleaner (it doesn't include the community imposing what is canonical onto a question which we don't generally do), but it isn't really the one asked (see also 'frame').

Comment: @ThomasMarkov If it helps, the current version of this question reads more like *"Are rules/lore from LoW acceptable support for answers on D&D 4e/5e questions?"* Asking if something is a valid support material is very much a meta topic. But you are correct that this question is quite borderline and a tweak in the wording either way could change which site it belongs on.

Comment: @linksassin I suppose you're right.Thanks for the perspective. Again, I do apologize if my confusion seemed like aggression at all, I certainly didn't intend to sound aggressive. It seemed totally obvious at first that this wasn't a meta question, but you and Someone_evil have been really helpful in giving some perspective.

Comment: I mean, if this is a meta question, then so should the other questions we have (especially with 5e) about what the official sources are. Right?

Comment: It could be that @linksassin did a better job than me in wording the main question,with "Are rules/lore from LoW acceptable support for answers on D&D 4e/5e questions?" But even with that, I am unclear whether this belongs on main or meta.

Comment: I think the issue is, basically, that the post is sort of asking 2 different questions; the title's basically asking "Is it OK to cite LoW in answering D&D 5e/4e questions?" while the body seems to focus on "Have the designers said anything about whether LoW is part of the 5e/4e ruleset?". My answer basically focuses on the title issue, since that seemed to be the fundamental part of the question that was answerable and appropriate for meta. (The question in the body would ostensibly be a question for mainsite, but would end up being closed because it's asking for designer reasons/statements.)

Comment: @V2Blast Bearing that in mind, I have edited the last paragraph (removed reference to designer statements) to keep the final question more in line with the overall post and title question.

Comment: @V2Blast Even then, questions about what is considered official are handled on main site.

Comment: @NautArch *“I mean, if this is a meta question, then so should the other questions we have (especially with 5e) about what the official sources are. Right?”* There's two ways to ask about this stuff: what is universally the case such that it affects all tables everywhere, and what is the case about how we specifically as a community do things here on this site? The former is manisite, the latter is meta. Like Someone_Evil and linksassin summarise above, this question is pretty borderline between the two, but it's on the meta side of the border.

Comment: For example, when I asked [are rulings from Dragon/Dungeon Magazine official?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33526/are-rulings-that-only-feature-in-dragon-dungeon-magazine-official), that's got nothing in particular to do with this site. That's asking about the state of the game. It affects me at any table I visit, and on any site in which I discuss the game. But this question here, while sorta asking both, is mainly asking—see the title—how we do things *here on this site,* which has no relevance to any other table, but it's going via "so what's the state of things?" along the way.

Comment: I'll note, in case it got missed, that Purple Monkey _did not instruct or request_ the querent to take their question to meta. They requested the querent to clarify their question. They also requested the querent to _consider_ whether their question is more appropriate for meta, leaving it fully up to the querent to decide for themselves. The querent, evidently having considered that, decided for themselves it was a meta question about practices here on this site.

Comment: @doppelgreener This is starting to feel like we need a meta question about a meta question :/ I'm having a hard time parsing the difference in the two cases. The rules we use to adjudicate answers are the official rules. Asking if "we" can use it here is equivalent to are they the official rules in my head. Or at least I'm having a hard time parsing the practical difference.

Comment: FWIW Purple Monkey's initial comment led me to clarify that the intent was to clear up if LOW was in-bounds vs out-of-bounds on this site for 4e/5e answers on main. In practical terms, would a main-site answer referencing LoW to make its case, be subject to an insta-close because this site doesn't consider LoW to be relevant canon? V2Blast's answer seems quite good. But other sites might see it differently.

Comment: I'm still just not seeing the difference. It very much seems like the question is simply "are these rules official?" Whether it's official for the site vs the game appears semantic, because the core is whether or not it is official for adjudication purposes for the game. And those questions are always on main.

Comment: @NautArch I can accept that it's a "bad" question, though I would appreciate a distinct statement as to how it could be changed into a good one, or, why it's so bad as to be irredeemable.

Comment: @ValleyLad The problem with this question (as I see it) relate to the notion of Expertise (which is a bit odd around here and always hard to pin down). As a meta question it tries to dictate what sources to use, which we prefer to leave to the answerers' expertise. As a main site question it fails to show the expertise to identify what is an RPG and what is a board game (when those lines are clear).

Comment: @Someone_Evil Thanks for trying to help, though I don't get your last statement there.  Obviously LoW is a board game whereas dnd5e is an RPG.  The question is whether any content from LoW as a branded D&D board game set in the same general world as dnd5e should be deemed relevant, or not, to answering questions about what is possible in dnd5e in that same general world. Happy to accept that the answer is "generally no"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### No. The board game's rules aren't part of any D&D edition's ruleset.

[*Lords of Waterdeep*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/board-games/lords-waterdeep) is a board game:

> *Lords of Waterdeep* is a strategy board game for 2-5 players. You
> take on the role of one of the masked Lords of Waterdeep, secret
> rulers of the city. Through your agents, you recruit adventurers to go
> on quests on your behalf, earning rewards and increasing your
> influence over the city.
>
> Expand the city by purchasing new buildings that open up new actions
> on the board, and hinder—or help—the other lords by playing Intrigue
> cards to enact your carefully laid plans.

As the name suggests, [*Lords of Waterdeep*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lords_of_Waterdeep) is set in Waterdeep, and thereby is based on the Forgotten Realms setting that was originally published as a campaign setting for *Dungeons & Dragons*.

However, that doesn't mean its rules are part of the D&D 4e or 5e ruleset, or the ruleset of any other D&D edition. The D&D 5e rules are those that appear in the official D&D 5e books, per this Q&A on RPG.SE: [Where do I find the "official" rules for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/where-do-i-find-the-official-rules-for-dd-5e)

There's playtest material that may end up being published in an official book, and there are optional rules that appear in the official books... But board games - even officially licensed ones - are not (and will presumably never be) a source of official rules or mechanics for the tabletop RPG.

Sometimes rules/mechanics in one medium will correspond to similar ones in another, but they often won't line up at all; even when mechanics in one medium do have a parallel to mechanics in another medium, that doesn't mean anything with regard to whether *Lords of Waterdeep* is actually part of the rules of D&D itself.

---

That said, that doesn't necessarily mean you're never allowed to mention the *Lords of Waterdeep* board game in your answers. For instance, if the 5e rules are silent/ambiguous on an issue, it could hypothetically be relevant to mention that the board game does allow for a certain thing to be done. However, even then, that alone is not enough to support the claim that the same thing should be allowed in the tabletop RPG; you'd need to elaborate on that point and better support it. And regardless, you should keep in mind that it specifically isn't evidence that that thing *is* allowed in the tabletop RPG, because it's not part of the tabletop RPG's rules.

Likewise, for questions about lore, it may be relevant to mention that a certain thing is supported by the board game's lore, especially if it's unaddressed by the 4e/5e books - just as it might be appropriate to reference relevant lore from past editions of D&D if a topic is not addressed in the current edition's material. Once again, you'd just need to keep in mind that it's not a direct part of the D&D lore, and that there may be inconsistencies between the board game's lore and the tabletop RPG's lore. (I also have no idea *when* the board game is set, or if it's even set at a particular point in time.)

Basically, you could mention something from the board game where relevant; it just needs to actually be relevant and support the point you're making - and you should keep in mind that something being true in the board game doesn't make it true in the tabletop RPG.

Comment: +1 I think what you are getting at revolves around the self-labeling of these materials:  that because LOW is described as a *strategy board game* whereas 5e is described as a *role-playing game* therefore, being two different types of games, they cannot be "the same game" for interpreting rules-oriented questions. Is that the crux of the matter?

Comment: @ValleyLad they're not the same game because they are *different games*. Different editions of actual D&D are all *role-playing games*, but they are also all different games and a question which is based on 5e's rules cannot be answered as if it was a 3e question or a 4e question. Even if sometimes it's helpful to refer to the rules or lore of other editions as a guideline for making reasonable rulings, those rulings are obviously not RAW for the edition of D&D in question.

Comment: @Carcer That's reasonable. Where I was coming from, was looking at the years 2008-14 as "the 4e era" of WotC and then 2014-present as "the 5e era", and since LOW came out on the cusp of these, that it could be taken to describe the same world, as it were, as one or these editions.  That's why I phrased the original question as merely handling questions of "what is possible" [in that world]. But it makes sense to say that even if they are set in the same world, they are different games, so there's no reason to expect applicability, and that's the end of the matter.

Comment: Pretty much. The lore might sometimes line up in multimedia franchises, and sometimes it might not - but the mechanics of different types of games almost never line up well, and even where they do sort of match, something being mechanically allowed by the rules of one product doesn't mean it's allowed by the rules of a different product, especially one in a different medium. For instance, whether something is possible or true in a video game based on Marvel Comics material doesn't tell us anything about whether it's possible or true in the original comics, nor in the MCU.